# Eclipse PDT 3.0 URL generation in debug missing?

Tags: eclipse-pdt

In Eclipse [PDT 2.2 debug settings](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13645632/debug_PDT_2.2.JPG) there was an URL settings input. I'm using this URL to manipulate the desired page to debug.

In [Eclipse PDT 3.0 debug settings](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13645632/debug_PDT_3.0.JPG) this setting is missing.

Currently, when debugging in 3.0, the URL is auto-generated to map targeted debug file: `localhost/__project/path/to/index.php`, but it should be targeting an arbitrary page `localhost/__site-example/contact-page`.

Any ideas how can I get the URL independent of targeted debugged file?

Or perhaps I should change the way I'm configuring the targeted debug URL?

Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a bug in PDT 3.0 which not just disables the function to edit the path but also disables the box for displaying path and option. By default key="auto_generated_url" value="true" , so by default you never have the possibility to edit URL.

As a workaround search for the configuration-file in your workspace f.e. /workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches/New_configuration.launch
and there you have to change the key mentioned above from true to false .

Then the URL-Box should show up again. (But don't dare to switch on auto generation again! .... )

Answer (score 1):

To mention, I think the issue/bug also involves 'Break On First Line'

I have disabled that option, in the individual debug configuration, and in the global debug preferences, but the debug still breaks on first line.

Your post helped me find that setting

in the same file, and now the break on first line is gone/fixed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found it useful to change the

```
stringAttribute key="base_url" value="http://xxxx
```

to your desired url in the launch configuration `(/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches/xxx.launch)` to launch the debug directly as required.

This helped me get rid of a pesky double slash when using rewrite for codeigniter due to the autogenerated