# Where is PDT "Debug All Pages" option in Eclipse Indigo?

Tags: eclipse-pdt

PDT is only debugging the first page launched in the debugger. Tons of tutorials and blog posts mention the **"Debug All Pages"** option in Debug Configurations | <Debug Configuration> | Advanced tab, but my Advanced tab only has "SSH Tunnel" and "Browser". I looked all over in Debug Configurations and Preferences and couldn't find "Debug All Pages". Also searched Google and SO. Was this [re]moved?

Screenshot: http://cl.ly/321u3M2K0C2G18091H2r

- Eclipse Indigo Service Release 1 (20110916-0149) on OS X 10.6.8
- PHP Development Tools (PDT) Runtime Feature   3.0.0.v20110516-1100-7V--F8NcJTTK4UE9TTJJ
- Remote debugging code on a server with PHP 5.3.2 and Xdebug 2.1.2.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a bit late for you but stumbled across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201321/eclipse-pdt-3-0-url-generation-in-debug-missing) other eclipse question that might help you fix your issue as well. If you edit ~/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches/xxx.launch (or similar for where ever your workspace is) then you can make the following change.

```
<stringAttribute key="debugPages" value="debugAllPages"/>
```

Comment: I'm equally amazed that this is proving so difficult to do. I have that line in my project's .launch, yet Xdebug still won't break on PHP scripts from a POST request. What gives?

Comment: My goodness... I got it to work after POSTing up the [XDEBUG_SESSION_START and KEY](http://xdebug.org/docs/remote#browser_session) fields...